# vega - Select column which contains the size of marks based on dropdown

Tags: vega

I have a question:
I have a dataset, let's say with four columns, some x value, some y value and two other variables.
I use a bubble chart for the visualization and I want to put a third variable on the size of the variables.
I created a dropdown menu for selecting the column which will be put on the size, using the "signals" and "bind" : {"input": "select" ...
However my problem is that I don't know how to connect the value of the signal to the marks and the size of the marks.
Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

you can do the below for controlling bubble size:

You may have already done Steps 1 and 2.

### Step 1 - Define a signal under `signals:` section

```
{
  "name": "sizeby", "value": "Cylinders",
  "bind": {
    "input": "select",
    "options": [
      "Cylinders",
      "Acceleration",
      "Miles_per_Gallon",
      "Horsepower"
    ]
  }
}
```

### Step 2 - Create a matching scale under `scales:` section

```
{
  "name": "color",
  "type": "ordinal",
  "range": {"scheme": "category10"},
  "domain": {"data": "source", "field": {"signal": "sizeby"}}
}
```

### Step 3 - Map it under `marks.encode.update:` section

```
"fill": {
  "scale": "color",
  "field": {"signal": "sizeby"}
},
"size": {
  "field": {"signal": "sizeby"}
}
```

all the configuration sections are connected by a signal `"name": "sizeby"`

Spec link: I [modified](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAE0JNjiLtOADZtM2uAA8kCU3G0B3OjG01xmQ0ihrS2k+Rw4rLaSMHaVgC0SFY0EJTSIM6y9GgATAAMGTLwNGRY6VkyOEiysu5kaAIySAyYbBA0AF5waCAlsomNZOJIJhBoANqgvQit6I0tTACeicR9DOMgAMLTJu7yigMyTBtooO44dW0QcAE+iWyq6gOogytrG4bbIJpQUGdeahKJALI0AQgAH0cIYgQBxPpmSQyAASbC2cBwbEchhAAF0AL6YqQjWxLKABJCKOYLcaYRSLGQ-O6gOCkDy3EAINgMU4MHCDACE9KCmFYngQ6MSHNk+iWFMWiQAZgiPmhJXBMVjcSBRksIDAaNLMKSTFLUNK+qdqRphiBeYy2gABAJkIKyADK0wQTDYJlQhJoUAA1lJtLbAsEADJIJhnT3rX0inBizxtS38zXazAAaTgsxkssU8tQiuVOLxYzaXt9cE6Mnm+vG4gYJhMpqGdIZmCZgftwWdrvdke9foDdodofDHtLPpjcaWwCri1Q2jjDAQlBnSplcvJlKVKqLSyYlM1eoN2RANPNiduoG6vRMJaJJJxIFF4tvcGJ2gA-NpBtltBl0do5z3NkYBAQsLRbNsbFifAWTZcsURhR9Y2fdBBisAAKABKf0MMw4UwPPNpBmtKC4lQWDTlkBD-WcYIUXI1l2Rwf8AD4nA2eiKMQNhSC5CcUJAQYgM1b90X9QlbBwdDcP9H9knoPDQNVQjUEvPJrzaeQTEwFAHyfeN0AkuwACUwntdDBjCWAEVE7QAGp5zOHT-SsmAbIARn-BytJ0sTfxomgUhgTDQO3NV8TaVyEUPGs6wbE8zWbPk22EmAGLgqjHEQ-SNSjOB0NSkKC1VdU2isTLEJXNBj1PJKrXQa1UvSyiEP4gyQFw0KwNK9AfJQSsyWqxtaXA5KiMa-c0q4iqAroxxmrgDlWPYuaFpZXi2qWXDtEiCIKq6kqIt6thkHcS5EtG+q1J6Po2lSpSkMnE4SnEArJswj83HEUhFEwdCAHIrH+-1CoA7Ra3rLqxLkfQUBGnqQDEBgc1aGRkZvXrYYIKBiXiUQfhkCkwggbMECbEBMGmUE2mlAFPBJGRrBwElMcwRdBn++FEWRVFFH+-8uQAXnBuLtAAMjF+d9HZ-7-kBEEwUhesJH57QhZF+txclhcEA5gB5ZRaHEVX1Yhm9ip3E5Ph8ctzvJik8ntFmQEJV8GZARRuNIBVNzAh2yCdtouWTHVEk99aN0WP3DcD9Bg61HUte0MdbZkdxTl+28+1t6PHbRCYE4sCXk6jH1U4ptgA4CLOy06Atob0QFyYRqxEkp6n0HWcQ3bD1lgh9qk1W9SO4BkFpFDYAfR7kE6kDO1SYZ0k5WRRmUaDOTp0C504ebRB9FDM8ZvykTI-26o6QEzCmqaWLue5kCeGH7vNNxkcRh6nsfDEnl-B6o06NCgDjHDRGK95RZnXiYTeIA5YKAVooCEUIfj70PkMU+Ugz6HWLIZd00VCY3zaAicoGkH6oIXlwRABJxRkARNMdyGQHr-znoAxeICkarwgRvfYiN1K3QmM0OAMxQLYmhjEBQ5NG5bUSGQZQm9FQyCYfPI0-Rp4InXh4O65h6hk0Jn2ZYfddSoGqBTOg1ct4Ih3iiPeqpJFtCvjIwKn8Z4ALQMok0J5lB8jaAEUOujMABAAAqlGIZUIxfizEwIBHA0ECClbQlCjIQcwRbjmggBSNgZcSy4PdmofxSwDZ5DOhAyGOCzDuyCFANg8huEQBdG6fo3CEZJKdHU90iR3D028L4EeaNkIGUvOksuAB1QKqQF5VVQGkB8VxvB0FmCNTwaSg4BHEGQeg6FgEA1OOcTwsh-qYQ+gAH0OV9TZ-1tlwBtns-0-0VzAylmzJcK4QoDWrNVSgAB2MCEyMiUHcgIZUMhJjjFABMgAbAAFmxA+EwYYzgXnCtgkAzThxnHaR4LwPgaDe1-tPHK3CZlQDmfbBQhiQBchWWsmAGzYZbOtrs-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-q7h43uGTfNdN7tNqeFnoTTNpNMgU2sdFcKp1QPXVldo4I5Q0Ytuzu4fuw9syT3HYzY5z87kb2rt2xm-b+FoUXY7v11VIBANVpA-dkbT3G1Gte2Do8H3Zso7aAt5NozU3UbQCDiHI6VtLFpp7PcfZI2PRQqABHnHkcdfPQAz6GO5y3pkLBq8J3gI7rxyIzEQA) an existing Vega example to add a dropdown element.